# How to combine IFS and AND formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested, formula

I have three columns (A,B,C) with multiple rows of data, some of the cells will have a text and some will be blank. In my fourth column I am trying to create a formula that returns a value once a certain combination of the text in columns A,B,C is identified.

I started off with the below  formula but I get stuck once I am trying the following logic "if cell B2 says ABC AND cell C2 says CBA then return 100".

=IFS(A2="ABC","100",B2="ABC","50",C2="ABC","50",AND(B2="ABC",C2="CBA","100"))

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Slightly rearranging your parameters within `ifs()` to:*

```js
=IFS(A2="ABC","100",
     AND(B2="ABC",C2="CBA"),"100",
     B2="ABC","50",
     C2="ABC","50",
     1,"--")
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Saving me again

Answer (score 0):

I would approach your problem like so:

```
=if(and(b2="ABC",C2="CBA"),100,"CHECK")
```

Both have to be true for and() to return true.

OR() will allow any one to be true to return true.

```
=if(OR(b2="ABC",C2="CBA"),100,"CHECK")
```